# How to create key vault secret with multiple values in one secret?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault, secret-key

I want to create a secret in the azure key vault which will be having multiple keys (like JSON).

e.g-

```sh
{
  "storageAccountKey":"XXXXX",
  "CognitiveServicesKey":"XXXX",
  "XXXXXx":"XXXX",
}
```

is it possible to create?

And then by using PowerShell script, I want to update a particular key in the above-created secret with a new one. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You will need to upload the content of a file as a secret. It can be done via the Azure CLI as follow:

```
az keyvault secret set --name [SECRET-NAME] --vault-name [VAULT_NAME] --file C:\path\to\file.txt --subscription [AZURE-SUBSCRIPTION-ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we will do that....it will reduce large number of calls to the KeyVault services.
I didn't understand how it will be a security threat if we use multiple keys in single secret.

Comment: One reason this is a security threat is it provides all or nothing access to the keys.  If an app wants access to just one of the secrets it will then gain access to all secrets even ones it doesn't necessarily need. As opposed to a more granular access control.  Just like with password management systems just because you may have access to one password shouldn't mean you have access to all passwords in the system.

Comment: Thank you very much